# unzip xz file into memory and read csv with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xz

I have a zipped file which contains a csv, compressed with [xz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XZ_Utils). I want to unzip it into the memory, and read wit pandas' `read_csv` method.
Pandas knows xz compression

```
data = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=file, index_col=0, compression='xz', engine='c')
```

I know how to unzip a file

```
input_zip=ZipFile(zip_file)
    input_zip=ZipFile(zip_file)

    file in input_zip.namelist():
```

But I do not know how to glue the two code together

Solution:

```
    input_zip=ZipFile(input_zip)

    for filename in input_zip.namelist():
        bytes = input_zip.read(filename)
        data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(bytes), index_col=0, compression='xz', engine='c')
```

Comment: `libarchive` supports reading from an archive without extracting on disk. You can use a `StringIO` object to pass it to pandas from there

Comment: What does the zipped file contain, i.e. what is the result of `input_zip.namelist()`?

Comment: the zipped file contains an archive, compressed with xz. `input_zip.namelist()` gives back the name of this file.

Comment: @Marat could you please show an example?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question and thought you want to extract content of an `.xz` file into memory. I see you worked out a solution already